# Understanding stack trace for message handling procedure

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I placed a `TApplicationEvents` component on my main form and added this event code:

```
procedure TAniWinMainForm.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
    if (ActiveMDIChild is TFormStartDialog) and
       (Msg.Message = WM_KEYDOWN) and (Msg.WParam = VK_F4) then
        Handled := True;
end;
```

After deploying the application I got reported an `EInvalidOp` error from an user via the following EurekaLog error report:

```
Modul Name   : KERNELBASE.dll
Typ          : EInvalidOp


|77A4E60A|ntdll.dll   |           |               |NtCallbackReturn                        |         |
|74515EAA|win32u.dll  |           |               |NtUserGetPointerInfoList                |         |
|754595F9|user32.dll  |           |               |GetPointerTouchInfo                     |         |
|778E3923|msvcrt.dll  |           |               |sqrt                                    |         |
|778E388D|msvcrt.dll  |           |               |sqrt                                    |         |
|778E387B|msvcrt.dll  |           |               |_CIsqrt                                 |         |
|778E3870|msvcrt.dll  |           |               |_CIsqrt                                 |         |
|75460AC0|user32.dll  |           |               |SendMessageW                            |         |
|77A235DB|ntdll.dll   |           |               |RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast|         |
|75470090|user32.dll  |           |               |CallWindowProcA                         |         |
|00CA5549|Program.exe |MAIN.pas   |TMainForm      |ApplicationEvents1Message               |700[1]   |
|7547BC0B|user32.dll  |           |               |DispatchMessageA                        |         |
|7547BC00|user32.dll  |           |               |DispatchMessageA                        |         |
|00D1376A|Program.exe |Program.dpr|               |                                        |1145[477]|
|772962C2|KERNEL32.DLL|           |               |BaseThreadInitThunk                     |         |
```

I guess the error has nothing to do with my code, but I do not understand what might be going on. 
Can anyone explain what could lead to this stack trace?
Shouldn't I see which function is calling CallWindowProcA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the call to `CallWindowProcA` is made by `ActiveMDIChild`. That is a property whose getter looks like this:

```
function TCustomForm.GetActiveMDIChild: TForm;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (FormStyle = fsMDIForm) and (FClientHandle <> 0) then
    Result := TForm(FindControl(SendMessage(FClientHandle, WM_MDIGETACTIVE, 0,
      0)));
end;
```

You'd expect to see the `SendMessage` immediately above `ApplicationEvents1Message` in the call stack, but I suspect that the EurekaLog stack tracing code is not good enough to find that when inside a Win32 API function. Now that call to `SendMessage` will call the window procedure of the client window, so a call to `CallWindowProcA` makes perfect sense.

As for the actual problem, this smells very like a problem with the Win32 code expecting floating point exceptions to be masked. I suggest that you mask exceptions before referring to `ActiveMDIChild`.

I would also strongly recommend that you change the order of the conditions in your `if` statement. This event is called for every single queued message that your program deals with. You really do not want to be reading the `ActiveMDIChild` property for each of those. Write the `if` statement like this:

```
if (Msg.Message = WM_KEYDOWN) and
   (Msg.WParam = VK_F4) and
   (ActiveMDIChild is TFormStartDialog) then
```

So you might re-write your event handler like this:

```
procedure TAniWinMainForm.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Save8087CW: Word;
begin
  if (Msg.Message = WM_KEYDOWN) and (Msg.WParam = VK_F4) then
  begin
    Save8087CW := Get8087CW;
    Set8087CW($027F); // this is the default Windows control word, with floating point exceptions masked
    if ActiveMDIChild is TFormStartDialog then
      Handled := True;
    Set8087CW(Save8087CW);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I see how your proposal avoids the bug. Thank you. But to fully understand: You mean `ActiveMDIChild` calls `SendMessage(FClientHandle, WM_MDIGETACTIVE,...)`
which calls the window procedure (of the MDI client area)? But doesn't this mean *everytime* a window procedure is called, should be protected by your proposed code? 
How do I know which Win32 code expects floating point exceptions to be masked? I am pretty sure `GetPointerTouchInfo` is nothing, that is called from our program directly.

Comment: Sure, this could happen elsewhere. Hard to say what you should do. I would not be surprised if the problem would go away if all you did was swap the order of the if statement.

Comment: I'll bet on that. It will reduce the number of calls of `GetActiveMDIChild` to nearly zero. I don't know how this stupid order of `if` conditions could have made it into the program in the first place...

Comment: What do you think: is `procedure TMyBaseForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage); begin  try    inherited WndProc(Message);  except on E: EInvalidOp do; end; end;` a good (additional) idea? (just in case).

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that. I'd personally fix the control word in the OnMessage handler.

Comment: Your code for the `OnMessage` handler should solve the problem for calls to `CallWindowProc` triggered by `GetActiveMDIChild`. I was concerned about other calls to `CallWindowProc` that might go wrong as well. Or did I misunderstand your last comment?

Comment: No, my last comment is daft. Wasn't thinking straight. It addresses the other problem, namely the system screwing with your control word state before you take over. But your issue is one of putting the control word state into a form suitable to call out. I would suspect that it's a defect that the system is calling sqrt in that way, and I suspect that it is confined only to certain versions of Windows. Perhaps by avoiding so many needless calls to `SendMessage` you will succeed in bypassing the errant call. Without debugging Windows itself it is hard to reason......

Comment: ..... So I think you should make just enough changes to make your program work correctly, and leave it at that.

Comment: And if your program does no floating point, then you could just mask exceptions at startup and be done with it.

Comment: Okay. I'll gonna apply only the proposed change and watch out what will happen. Thank you for your help.